# Convert Decimal to Binary - Induction

Tags: algorithm, induction

I read the page 2 of [Mathematical Induction](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2013/cmsc351/notes/induc_alg1.pdf), I have difficulty of understanding of

> The Induction Hypothesis is “If m is the integer represented by the
>   binary array b[1,2 . . . k], then n = 2 ^ k * t + m”

1) What is **m**?

2) And for t is even the **m is unchangeable** while for t is odd the **m=m+2^k**, how?

Please explain above points. Thanks

Comment: Belongs on a maths site as it is not a programming question. Try http://mathoverflow.net

Comment: It is algorithm question to be exact. So is programming question.

Comment: Quoting the doc you linked: "If m is the integer represented by binary..."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` is an integer represented by the binary array **in the step k,** that is probably the information that is not stressed enough clearly.

Let's take an example. When you are converting `n = 11` to binary, the final result will be `1011`. After step `k = 2` you converted two lowest significant bits, so the current binary array is `11`, which gives `m = 3`. You divided 11 by 2 twice, so `t = 11/2/2 = 2`. Obviously, `2 ^ k * t + m = 2^2 * 2 + 3 = 11 = n.` That explains your second question as well, because for odd `t` the next bit in the binary representation will be `1`, which increases the current binary representation by `2^k`.

Comment: Thanks for giving great explanation.